# How to Calculate BMI in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing, static-methods

I'm writing a program that takes the users input for height and weight then calculates the Body Mass Index from this. It uses separate methods for height, weight and BMI, these methods are called from main. The problem I'm having is I have absolutely no clue how to put the input from weight and height methods into the BMI method. This is what the code looks like:

```
public class BMIProj {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int heightInInches()
    {

       System.out.println("Input feet: ");
       int x;
       x = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Input Inches: ");
       int y;
       y = input.nextInt();

       int height = x * 12 + y;

       return height; 
    }

    public static int weightInPounds()
    {
        System.out.println("Input stone: ");
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input pounds ");
        int y;
        y = input.nextInt();

        int weight = x * 14 + y;

        return weight;
    }

    public static void outputBMI()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        heightInInches();
        weightInPounds();
        outputBMI();

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: "return" is important. Next hint: you tagged your post with "parameters", but none of your functions uses any.

Comment: AFAIK, the original BMI calculations use the metric system (height in cm, weight in kilograms). I guess you need a conversion factor for the imperial one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to do a little bit more learning in java, specifically variables, declaring, initializing, etc.. Also learn class, constructors, etc..

1. You need fields for the class to save the inputed variables
2. I created a constructor to initialize the variables
3. You don't need to return anything in the methods if all you are doing is assigning values to your class fields and outputting info.

I did the curtsy of calculating the bmi for you

Anyway

```
public class BMIProj {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Class vars
   int height;
   int weight;
   double bmi;

   //Constructor
   public BMIPrj(){
     //Initialize vars 
     height = 0;
     weight = 0;
     bmi = 0;
   }

    public static void heightInInches()
    {

       System.out.println("Input feet: ");
       int x;
       x = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Input Inches: ");
       int y;
       y = input.nextInt();

       int height = x * 12 + y;

       return height; 
    }

    public static void weightInPounds()
    {
        System.out.println("Input stone: ");
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input pounds ");
        int y;
        y = input.nextInt();

        int weight = x * 14 + y;

        return weight;
    }

    public static void outputBMI()
    {
      System.out.println("BMI: " + (( weight / height ) x 703));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        heightInInches();
        weightInPounds();
        outputBMI();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of a method to a parameter like so:

`int weight = weightInPounds();`

When calling a method, you can pass in parameters:

`outputBMI(weight);`

The rest is up to you.